# Minimum cover of set of functional dependency

Tags: database, relational-database, functional-dependencies

I was going through the conditions of minimum cover of a set of function dependencies.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency#Irreducible_function_depending_set), it is mentioned that the right hand side can have only single attribute. So `{A1A2 → B1B2}` is not possible. It should be split as `{A1A2 → B1, A1A2 → B2}`.

But in DBMS by Korth, the following condition is there

```
Each left side of a functional dependency in Fc is unique. That is, there are no
two dependencies A1 → B1 and A2 → B2 in Fc such that A1 = A2.
```

So, according to this `{A1A2 → B1, A1A2 → B2}` is not possible. The dependencies should be combined as `{A1A2 → B1B2}` to avoid repetition.

Please clarify which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me to be a difference in notation, and nothing more. These two sets of FDs are equivalent.

- {A1A2 → B1}
- {A1A2 → B2}
- {A1A2 → B1B2}

Most of the automated tools I've used express the minimum cover as you see in the first set. Your text seems to prefer the second set.

The two different expressions have no effect on reducibility or coverage or closure, which are the real issues in computing a minimum cover. You *could* argue that the first version, which has no more than one non-prime attribute on the right-hand side, is better because it's closer to a decomposition in 6NF.

But you should use the version your text and your professor require, keeping in mind that it's a false requirement. It's false in the sense that changing the notation from the second version to the first has no effect on whether you've actually found the minimum cover, and it has no substantial effect on the work you need to do to compute the minimum cover.

Comment: Thats right. It depends on the requirements. But I just wanted to know which examples can I consider in Minimal Cover according to the definition. Are canonical cover and minimal cover different?

Comment: *Canonical cover* and *minimum cover* mean the same thing in all the authors I've read. They're both the minimum set of FDs that imply all the relevant FDs. (You can derive all relevant FDs from the minimum cover.) I don't understand the question, "which examples can I consider in Minimal Cover according to the definition?"